# Lisp update list

Tags: list, lisp, autolisp

Hi I'm new with AutoCad lisp and am trying to speed up my work just a little with some simple routine but I hit a wall and can't to figure this out and I have a strong filling that there is a simple solution. So...

I made a list named "koord":

```
(setq koord (list (cons "1" "10,10,10")))
```

the result is dotted pair: `("1" . "10,10,10")`

after that I add to this list for example:

```
(setq koord (append koord (list (cons "2" "20,20,20"))))
(setq koord (append koord (list (cons "3" "30,30,30"))))
```

now the result is: `("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "20,20,20") ("3" . "30,30,30")`

at this moment I would like to update the second dotted pair and make my list look like this:

`("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "60,60,60") ("3" . "30,30,30")`

but I don't know how... If I append like this

```
(setq koord (append koord (list (cons "2" "60,60,60"))))
```

than I get this result:

```
("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "20,20,20") ("2" . "60,60,60") ("3" . "30,30,30")
```

which wouldn't be too bad if I know how to retrieve this one `("2" . "60,60,60")`

If I try

```
(assoc "2" koord)
```

it gives back the first occurrence i.e. `("2" . "20,20,20")`

So, is there a way not to add but to update a value in dotted pair or to retrieve the last one appended - not the first one?

Comment: The result of `(list (cons "1" "10,10,10"))` isn't `("1" . "10,10,10")` but `(("1" . "10,10,10"))`

Comment: instead of appending, simply prepend it like this: `(setq koord (cons (cons "2" "60,60,60") koord))`. Next time you call `(assoc "2" koord)` you'll get the new pair `'("2" . "60,60,60")`. The previous pair will still be inside the `koord` list, but won't be seen by `assoc`, which always picks the first match.

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks! I tried your solution and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the record, you can do this:

```
(def alist-update (alist key value)
  "Update the value of a key or add a cell."
  (let ((cell (assoc key alist)))
    (if cell
        (setf (cdr cell) value)
        (acons key value alist))))
(setq alist (alist-update () 1 "a"))
(assoc 1 alist)
==> (1 . "a")
(setq alist (alist-update alist 1 "b"))
(assoc 1 alist)
==> (1 . "b")
```

While you are using AutoLisp and not Common Lisp (note that CL [`assoc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_assocc.htm) uses `eql` for comparison by default and would thus return `nil` for `(assoc "1" ...)`) or Emacs Lisp,  I still suggest that you look through the [Association Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) in the manual.

Comment: Thank you! I also read in the meantime on some forum that I can use: (assoc "2" (reverse koord)) - in my example. This "reverse" will give me the last entered pair

Answer (score 0):

Given your list of dotted pairs:

```
_$ (setq koord '(("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "20,20,20") ("3" . "30,30,30")))
(("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "20,20,20") ("3" . "30,30,30"))
```

The following will substitute the second item for a new item:

```
_$ (subst '("2" . "60,60,60") (assoc "2" koord) koord)
(("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "60,60,60") ("3" . "30,30,30"))
```

However, note that this will substitute all occurrences of the original item, e.g.:

```
_$ (setq koord '(("2" . "20,20,20") ("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "20,20,20") ("3" . "30,30,30") ("2" . "20,20,20")))
(("2" . "20,20,20") ("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "20,20,20") ("3" . "30,30,30") ("2" . "20,20,20"))

_$ (subst '("2" . "60,60,60") (assoc "2" koord) koord)
(("2" . "60,60,60") ("1" . "10,10,10") ("2" . "60,60,60") ("3" . "30,30,30") ("2" . "60,60,60"))
```